# What is the difference between $L$ and $\mathcal{L}$? How does one find the Lagrangian

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm following a course of Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics, but I'm getting somewhat confused. Could someone explain the difference between $L$ and $\mathcal{L}$?

I'm calling both *"the Lagrangian of the system"*, but they seem te be different?

Also I'm somewhat confused in how to find these functions. The big advantage seems to be that, using the Euler-Lagrange equations you can *easily* describe the motion of the system. However to find the Lagrangian $L=T-V$ one needs to know the kinetic and potential energy. Which depend on $\dot x, \dot y, \dot z, \ldots$ Seems to me that to find $T$ you already need to know the motion of the system?

I guess I'm starting to mix everything together, could someone clarify?

Comment: $\mathcal{L}$ is probably the Lagrangian *density*. It's a thing you integrate to get the Lagrangian.

Comment: $\dot{x}$ etc are considered independent from $x$ etc.